# Passing return value of a function as an argument

Tags: function, arguments, return-value

What are some ways of passing the return value of one function as an argument to another?

What are some examples in programming languages that you favor, JS, Python, etc?

Answer (score 3):

do you mean like the following C code:

```
int foo(void) {
    return 4; /* XKCD standard random number */
}

int bar(void) {
     do_something(2,foo());
     return 0;
}
```

That has nothing to do with functional programming [read up at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming ]

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = AnotherFunction(ReturnFunction(someVariable));
```

where `AnotherFunction()` accepts the same type that `ReturnFunction()` returns.

Most modern languages allow this.

Answer (score 0):

In F# you can pipe it like so

```
 f() |> g
```

(assuming `f` returns a `T` and `g` takes a `T`)

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell,

```
x . f . g 5
```